# Custom props are not being passed to stateless child components

Tags: reactjs, react-props

So after doing [this freeCodeCamp Challenge](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/front-end-libraries/react/pass-props-to-a-stateless-functional-component) about passing props to stateless components, I tried to copy the code into [codePen](https://codepen.io/TaraBryn/pen/zgoJPM?editors=1111) to save for reference later on, but the props are not being passed.

So If I assign a default value, the default value works fine, but if I try to remove the default value, the prop just comes back `null` and overriding the default value doesn't work. (Incidentally, when I try to use propTypes and make it a required, it doesn't render at all).

```
const CurrentDate = (props) => {
  console.log(props.date)
  return (
    <div>
      { /* change code below this line */ }
      <p>The current date is: {props.date}</p>
      { /* change code above this line */ }
    </div>
  );
};

CurrentDate.defaultProps = {date: "test"};
//CurrentDate.propTypes = {date: PropTypes.string.isRequired};

class Calendar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>What date is it?</h3>
        { /* change code below this line */ }
        <CurrentDate date={Date()}/>
        { /* change code above this line */ }
      </div>
    );
  }
};

console.log(Date());

ReactDOM.render(<CurrentDate/>,$("#target")[0]); //target is the id of the only element (div) in the html
```

Comment: Shouldnt it be `ReactDOM.render(<Calendar />,$("#target")[0]);`

Comment: @Mobeen lol yeah you're right, that actually fixed the problem...stupid mistake >< Thanks!

Comment: @Mobeen, do you happen to see anything wrong with the propTypes declaration?

Comment: Nope, No issues